# Numpy array to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a `numpy` array

```
[['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Setosa'],
 ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Versicolor']]
```

How to convert it to a dictionary such that

```
{['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2']:'Setosa', ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2']:'Versicolor'}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you ment 'Setosa' and 'Versicolor' instead of 'Iris-setosa' in that example output, right?

Comment: this isn't really specific to numpy is it?

Comment: @TooTone Indeed. The solution I proposed works fine on regular nested lists as well.

Comment: @Joost I know: I tried it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dictionary you're currently specifying is invalid, since the keys of your dictionaries cannot be `list` objects. However, you could change them to tuples. As tuples are immutable, they can be used as keys.

A dictionary comprehension that converts the sample case you have provided might look like this:

```
a = numpy.array([['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Setosa'],
                 ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Versicolor']])
b = {tuple(x[:-1]) : x[-1] for x in a}
```

It creates a tuple from the first n-1 elements of each list, and then assigns the last element as the value. The resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
{('5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2'): 'Setosa', ('4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2'): 'Versicolor'}
```